# Foreach inside of Foreach Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to write a foreach loop that will find each distinct category type, and then list each Title that has that category assignment.

For example:

```
@model IEnumerable<CMESurvey.Models.SurveyProgramModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgramType.ProgramType)</h2>
    foreach (var listing in Model)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => listing.ProgramTitle)</li>
        </ul>
    }
}
```

Survey Response Model:

```
  public class SurveyProgramModel
{

    [Key]
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }

    public int ProgramYear { get; set; }

    public int ProgramStatusId { get; set; }

    public string ProgramTitle { get; set; }



public virtual SurveyProgramModel SurveyProgramModel { get; set; }

public virtual PersonModel PersonModel { get; set; }
```

}

I am running into 2 issues.

1.)  I need it to only display each category once, rather than listing the category for each item instance.

2.)  It is displaying all ProgramTitle, rather than just the the the ProgramTitle for that loop.

Not sure what the syntax I should be using is.

Comment: Your inner foreach makes a single item list for each listing in model. Did you intend for just the `<li>` to be in the inner loop?

Comment: Can you post the code for `SurveyProgramModel`?

Comment: Yes, but I need it to loop for each item that has the outer loop as it's category (or ProgramType)

Comment: You are looping the entire IEnumerable in the inner foreach for every item when you loop through the IEnumerable in the outer foreach. If `item` from your outer loop is an enumerable itself, your inner foreach should be `foreach (var listing in item)`.  If it is not, you have more complex logic that should be done in the controller before it lands here.

Comment: I tried that and got an error saying: "CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'CMESurvey.Models.SurveyProgramModel' because 'CMESurvey.Models.SurveyProgramModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: And the code for `SurveyResponseModel`, please.

Comment: Ok, this has been added.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly then it should be like

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { 
  <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgramType.ProgramType)</h2> 
  foreach (var listing in item.SurveyResponseModels) 
  { 
     <ul> 
       <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => listing.ProgramTitle)</li> 
     </ul> 
  } 
}
```

Comment: No, ProgramTitle is on the SurveyProgramModel, not the SurveyResponseModel.

Comment: This is still displaying all of ProgramType's, not just the Distinct (or unique) ones

Comment: Could you give some mock up data and then your expected result

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to group your enumeration by ProgramType in your controller. This will keep the view nice and clean.

```
IEnumerable<CMESurvey.Models.SurveyProgramModel> models = Foo(); //however you got them...
var grouped = models.GroupBy(s => s.ProgramType.ProgramType);
return View(grouped);
```

Then, your view is much simpler. (After you fix the type of your model).

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Key)</h2>
    <ul> 
    for(int j = 0; j < Model[i].Count; j++)
    {
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i][j].ProgramTitle)</li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Alternative:

Or, you make a list of lists:

```
var models = Foo();
var grouped = models.GroupBy(s => s.ProgramType.ProgramType)
                    .Select(x => x.Select(y => y))
                    .ToList();
return View(grouped);
```

Then your view is slightly changed:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].First().ProgramType.ProgramType)</h2>
    <ul> 
    for(int j = 0; j < Model[i].Count; j++)
    {
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i][j].ProgramTitle)</li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: I like the way that looks!  I tried implementing that and I'm getting this error: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CMESurvey.Models.SurveyProgramModel>'
"

Comment: Sounds like I missed a .ToList() somewhere. An IEnumerable can't index, but a List can. I'm not sure which alternative you used, but you probably just need to add .ToList().