# Creating a list of checkboxes from a DbSet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table in the database that is a list of Products. Then I have a Fundraiser class (made into a controller and views) that will have a "collection" of Products. The point is that "for this fundraiser, I am selling these selected products".

My idea is to have a list of checkboxes so that the user can select which products are to be included in the fundraiser. I know that the typical way of doing this is to have an intermediary table that has a compound key of ProductID and FundraiserID. I don't want to do this.

Instead my idea is to make the list of products as checkboxes, use JavaScript to create a JSON string as the user selects/deselects the checkboxes, then save that JSON string into a simple text field in the Fundraiser table.

```
public class Fundraiser
{
    public int FundraiserID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string ItemsList { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, there are two ways that I'm thinking this can go.

1. How do I write raw HTML so that I can manually iterate through the resultset of the Products table and create the checkboxes. Right now, the HTML I write is shown literally on the page instead of interpreted.

   ```
   ViewData["ProductList"] = "<input type='checkbox' id='prod12' checked>";
   // Is escaped or something so that it does not render as an HTML input
   ```

OR

2. Is there an HTML helper or some other tool that will do this through class methods or something (so that I can do it in the 'proper' OOP style)?

   ```
   ViewData["ProductList"] = new ListOfCheckBoxes(_context.Products, "ProductID"......
   ```

I have a background in PHP programming, and I rarely used third-party code, so having all these high-level "helpers" is really confusing for me. I just want to write the code!

Comment: You shouldn't use Entity Framework model classes directly in your MVC models. It can end up getting you in to trouble.

Comment: You didn't supply any of your current attempt to write the view.  I think you should review some related examples, like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316971/foreach-inside-of-foreach-razor  Also, are you using the Razor or . Net View Engine?

Comment: Similiar to Bradley Uffner's comment, I would make the model relate to how you're going to use it on the page, and not how you are going to store it.  I'd actually work with a List of Products as part of the view model.  Either way, you'll need a list of available products, and knowledge if the product is active for the fundraiser.  I'd leave all the html to your view and html helpers.

Comment: Like I said, if I have a DbSet<Products>, is there an HTML helper that can produce a list of checkboxes? OR...how do I SIMPLY use my Controller to write HTML code that will get interpreted by the browser, not just displayed as though it was in a PRE tag? What's the statement?

Comment: That is a awful approach - from a db point of view, suggest you read this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) and from a mvc point of view, you will not get string-typed 2-way model binding or validation.

Comment: As for how to generate the view correctly, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example